# Mongodb odm docrine - self reference many to many (get specific data)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, php-mongodb, doctrine-odm

I want to know how can I select specific friend from this model.
The model structure is here:

```php
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Users", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    public $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Users", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     */
    public $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add friend
     * @param Users $user
     */
    public function addFriend(Users $user) {
        $user->friendsWithMe[] = $this;
        $this->myFriends[] = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get friends
     * @return Array $myFriends
     */
    public function getFriends() {
        return $this->myFriends;
    }
```

To get user friends I use this code:

```
foreach($userSearch->getFriends() as $friend){
    $output .= "&nbsp;FriendName: " . $friend->getFirstName() . " - ID: " . $friend->getId() . "<br>";
}
```

So if I don't want to get all friend and loop over them how can I get specific users or user(friend/s) lets say older then 20 years.

**EDITED**
Here im adding the document that is in the collection so im looking for a way to retrive one of the two friend with query for example who is older then x years instead of for loop on client side.

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("503f3028e71a38840d000000"),
   "birthdate": ISODate("2012-08-30T09: 19: 36.0Z"),
   "email": "mail",
   "firstName": "asd",
   "myFriends": {
     "0": {
       "$ref": "Users",
       "$id": ObjectId("503e1683921da8c80b000002"),
       "$db": "testing" 
    },
     "1": {
       "$ref": "Users",
       "$id": ObjectId("503e0a8ee71a38080b000001"),
       "$db": "testing" 
    } 
  },
   "password": "123",
   "role": {
     "$ref": "UserRoles",
     "$id": ObjectId("50486ba1e71a384c15000000"),
     "$db": "testing" 
  },
   "username": "gizmo" 
}
```

**Note:** I'm using with module for ZF2 project (ZF2 + DoctrineOdmMongodb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a managed user document `$user` and an instance of `UserRepository` `$userRepository`.

```
$users = $userRepository->createQueryBuilder()->field('myFriends')->includesReferenceTo($user)->field('age')->gt(20)->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that looking at the API docs is handy as the regular documentation is a bit behind and doesn't include the references expression method mentioned here. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/namespace-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Query.html

Comment: I'm not sure if i have userRepository, i use this code: 
`$this->dm->getRepository('Application\Model\Users')->createQueryBuilder()->field('myFriends')->references($user)->field('firstName')->equals("Dragan")->getQuery()->execute()` and the result are 0 when i try to foreach (loop)

Comment: If you haven't implemented a custom repository class, Doctrine (both ORM and ODM) will utilize a vanilla implementation (see: [here](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=repository#custom-repositories)). Both the Builder and Query classes have a `debug()` method that you can use to examine the query that will be sent to Mongo. This is helpful for testing the query against Mongo directly (e.g. in its JS shell).

Comment: I just submitted a correction to suggest [`includeReferenceTo()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Query.Expr.html#_includesReferenceTo) instead of `references()`, which is necessary since we're working with an array of references.

Comment: @jmikola If you believe this answer is incorrect, post your own so we can give you the rep.

Comment: @jmikola thanks, ill try this and will report result then ill mark as best answer if i dont get any problem.

Comment: @cadrell0: I only mentioned it in the comment because I wasn't sure how long it'd take the edit to appear. This answer was on point except for the method name. @EmrahMehmedov: it looks like you're still using `references()` in your paste. See the revision on this answer.

Comment: @jmikola ok i change it this return a data but not only friend its search the all records http://pastie.org/4695397 how can i make it to search only friends.

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. It looks like you replaced the references criteria for `myFriends` with a match on some field value (I presume that exists on the referenced friend documents, but isn't actually stored in `myFriends`).

Comment: @jmikola i edit the content of the question if you can see. currently i can loop the friends it's ok but intead of loop ing on client side for every friend i want to make a query that will give me that specified friend for any user if it is possible.

Comment: I believe the functionality you're asking for is collection filtering, which currently exists in Doctrine ORM (see [PR #381](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/381)); however, it has yet to be documented and it also hasn't been ported over to ODM.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter.

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html for the ORM equivalent. Filters were implemented in ODM a couple of months ago, and can be configured through DoctrineMongoODMModule.

Basically, you create your filter class. Add a line to the DoctrineMongoODMModule config, and then turn the filter on with `$documentManager->getFilterCollection()->enable('myFilter');`

You'll find some examples of filter usage here https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tests/Functional/FilterTest.php

Comment: Use @Lusitanian's suggestion above. It's a better solution in this case.

Comment: im trying @Lusitanian option but i dont get any result.